# Adding GeoJSON layer using variable in OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers, geojson, addlayer

When I use url reference of open layers and give a path from a local directory, then it correctly shows the layer on the map, but want to add through constant variable **(comming)** because I am getting it as a global Appolo client variable and I have used both ways, from URL and features method, but still unable to show the layer on the map using **comming** variable.

```
import { useState, useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import React from 'react';
import Index from './sidebar';
import Map from 'ol/Map.js';
import View from 'ol/View.js';
import OSM from 'ol/source/OSM.js';
import TileLayer from 'ol/layer/Tile.js';
import { fromLonLat } from 'ol/proj.js';
import XYZ from 'ol/source/XYZ.js';
import { Vector as VectorLayer } from 'ol/layer';
import { Vector as VectorSource } from 'ol/source';
import { GeoJSON } from 'ol/format';
import { useReactiveVar } from '@apollo/client';
import { Files } from '../lib/appolo client/cache'; '''

const Home = () => {
  var comming = useReactiveVar(Files)
  if (comming) {
    console.log("Features are : ", comming)
  }
  const mapRef = useRef(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!mapRef.current) return;

    const map = new Map({
      layers: [
        new TileLayer({
          visible: 'false',
          type: 'base',
          source: new OSM()

        }),

      ],
      view: new View({
        center: fromLonLat([35.7915, 78.7811]),
        zoom: 5,
      }),
      target: mapRef.current,
    });
    // const vectorSource = new VectorSource({
    //   // url: '/Data/sample.geojson',
    //   url: comming,
    //   format: new GeoJSON()
    // });
    // console.log("Vactorr Source is : ", vectorSource)
    // // Create a vector layer and add it to the map
    // const vectorLayer = new VectorLayer({
    //   source: vectorSource,
    //   visible: true
    // });

    // const addLayerFromGeoJSON = (comming) => {
    if (comming) {
      const vectorSource = new VectorSource({
        features: (new GeoJSON()).readFeatures(comming, {
        }),
      });
      // Create a vector layer and add it to the map


      const vectorLayer = new VectorLayer({
        source: vectorSource,
        visible: true,
      });
      map.addLayer(vectorLayer);

    }

  }, [comming]);
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <Index />
      </div>
      <div className='ml-[446px]' ref={mapRef} style={{ width: 'calc(100%-446px)', height: '100vh' }} />

    </div>
  )
}

export default Home
```

here is my console.log **comming** variable result:

```
Features are :  {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          102.0,
          0.5
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "prop0": "value0"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "LineString",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            102.0,
            0.0
          ],
          [
            103.0,
            1.0
          ],
          [
            104.0,
            0.0
          ],
          [
            105.0,
            1.0
          ]
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "prop0": "value0",
        "prop1": 0.0
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              100.0,
              0.0
            ],
            [
              101.0,
              0.0
            ],
            [
              101.0,
              1.0
            ],
            [
              100.0,
              1.0
            ],
            [
              100.0,
              0.0
            ]
          ]
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "prop0": "value0",
        "prop1": {
          "this": "that"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: If you use `readFeatures` you must specify `dataProjection` (EPSG:4326) and `featureProjection` (the view projection) options.  Otherwise to use the variable as a url you must make it a data url `'data:,' + encodeURIComponent(comming)` for a string or `'data:,' + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(comming))` for an object variable.

Comment: Thanks for reply mike:

But it still does not show my data, I have applied both ways, either from readFeatures and by using URL:

see below:

`const vectorSource = new VectorSource({
        features: (new GeoJSON()).readFeatures(comming, {
          dataProjection: 'EPSG:4326',
          featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857'
        }),
        
      });`

and 

`const vectorSource = new VectorSource({
          // url: '/Data/sample.geojson',
          url: 'data:,' + encodeURIComponent(comming),
          format: new GeoJSON()
        });`